# Sending mail Power Shell 4

Tags: powershell

Good Day! Help please, use this script here:

```
$file = "C:\Reports\Log_1.txt"
$FileExists = Test-Path $file

If ($FileExists -eq "False") {
Write-Host "sending mail"

$mail = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
 

$mail.From = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("test@gmail.com")
$mail.To.Add("test@gmail.com")
 

$mail.Subject = "report";

$mail.Body = get-content $file
 

$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

$smtp.host = "smtp.domen.com"
$smtp.port="25"
 

$Credentials = new-object System.Net.networkCredential
$Credentials.domain = "smtp.domen.com"
$Credentials.UserName = "test@gmail.com"
$Credentials.Password = "rgrthbdgfhytju"
$smtp.Credentials = $Credentials
 

$smtp.Send($mail)
}

# else {
#Write-Host "File $file not found"
#}
```

I get two errors trying to connect the two mail servers.
In the first case, the connection error and the second authentication error:

1. **error 1 (gmail.com): Exception calling with this 1 argument This operation has timed out.**
2. **error 2 (corporate post):  Exception calling with this 1 argument Failure sending mail.**

   Sorry,I can not insert a picture of the limitations.

Comment: This looks like a connection error. from the machine where you are running this script can you telnet to port 25 of the SMTP server? Also what version of powershell are you running...because from V2 you can use the `send-mailmessage` cmdlet which would simplify things quite a bit.

Comment: Could you post the full error message? The second one probably includes an SMTP error code

Comment: connection error if enter mail.ru else connection OK if enter smtp.mail.ru, Power shell 4.0

Comment: Full text error:  Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
At C:\scripts\Post_log.ps1:33 char:1
+ $smtp.Send($mail)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
 and Exception calling "Send" with "1" argument(s): "Failure sending mail."
At C:\scripts\Post_log.ps1:33 char:1
+ $smtp.Send($mail)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException

Comment: Er... what's wrong with `Send-MailMessage`?

Comment: Why not, and do not tell me, there can be manual Send-MailMessage? or give an example.